# Extract Graph from DBpedia, by number of HOPS, Direction

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, sparql, dbpedia, google-knowledge-graph

[image: Sample graph]

In the above graph [which is in dbpedia], I want to extract information about TIM COOK, with hops, IF I put hop as 1, I would need all the first level information about TIM COOK, like Masters, APPLE, Car

If hops are 2, I need Masters, APPLE, Car, United States

Is there any way I could extract such graph ?

I would like to pass direction (Incoming, Outgoing) also to extract graph.

Could you please help me with SPARQL query?

Comment: is possible to some extent via SPARQL, yes. Just use a `CONSTRUCT` query with the appropriate triple patterns

Comment: @AKSW Thanq SO much.. could you please suggest any tutorial on this, or any materials where i can study on this...

Comment: You simply have to read about RDF and SPARQL. Any SPARQL tutorial is sufficient to solve this, its basically defining a pattern that matches the subgraph you're interested

Comment: Note, the subgraph can become pretty large, especially when also considering incoming edges and combination with authority nodes.

Comment: hi @ChaitanyaPatil were you able to solve your problem, if done can you please share it